# How to create a grid with tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image]

I would like to create a grid like this with tickpicture, but I don't know how to draw the points where lines match.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There might be wiser approaches, but to me it looks like something that can be solved with foreaches and manual placement of nodes.

[image: grid]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{dot/.style={fill=black,circle}}

\foreach\l[count=\y] in {E,...,A}
{
\draw (0,\y) -- (7.5,\y);
\node at (-0.5,\y){\l};
}

\foreach \x in {1,2,...,7}
{
\draw (\x,0) -- (\x,5.5);
\node at (\x,-0.5){\x};
}

\node[dot] at (1,5){};
\node[dot] at (2,3){};
\node[dot] at (2,4){};
\node[dot] at (3,1){};
\node[dot] at (4,4){};
\node[dot] at (5,2){};
\node[dot] at (6,3){};
\node[dot] at (7,2){};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you go about it via `\foreach\x[count=\xi]in{A,...,E}{...}` it travels both the letters and also keeps a counter.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, to keep it compatible with the rest of the code, I used `\foreach\l[count=\y] in {E,...,A}`

Answer (score 9):

This solution allows you to place the points on the grid by referencing the indices, such as (B,2).

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mydot}[3][]{%
    \node[circle,inner sep=1.5pt,#1] at (#2 -| #3){};
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \y[count=\iy] in {E,D,...,A}
    \draw (0,\iy) -- ++(7.5,0) node(\y)[at start,left]{\y};
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,7}
    \draw (\x,0) -- ++(0,5.5) node(\x)[at start,below]{\x};
\foreach \n/\m in {A/1,B/2,B/4,C/2,C/6,D/5,D/7}
    \mydot[fill=black]{\n}{\m};
\mydot[fill=red]{E}{3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to use `\filldraw[gray](x,y)circle[radius=2pt];` where (x,y) are the coordinates of the point on a `grid`.

Below is a sample of my code to place dots on a grid:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(-5.5,-5.5) grid (5.5,5.5);
\filldraw[gray](0,0)circle[radius=2pt];
\filldraw[gray](1,1)circle[radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\label{my_grid}A grid with two points !}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```